# MVC 3 - AntiForgeryConfig - Namespace Missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting error message 'The type or namespace name

> 'AntiForgeryConfig' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System.Web.WebPages' (are you missing an assembly reference?)'

This happens when I try to add below code in `Global.asax.cs` file.

I have already included namespaces `System.Web.Helpers` and `System.Web.WebPages`.

```
AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressIdentityHeuristicChecks = true;
```

Do I need to include any other namespace here?

Answer (score 0):

What version of System.Web.WebPages are you using? AntiForgeryConfig isn't included in v1, so you might need to upgrade to v2 to be able to use it.